# Assign TCP and UDP ports to multiple IP addresses in home network

Tags: networking, tcp, port

I have a question about port forwarding with my wifi router. For games such as battlefield series certain TCP and UDP ports have to be open. In my home network I have assigned these ports to a PC and would also want to do that with another PC. My netgear router does not allow me to do that is there a work around.

Comment: This seems a better topic for http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can forward different ports to different systems for example:

For Internet Server set: Start Port as 80, End Port as 80, Local Ip address as 192.168.0.3
For FTP Server set: Start Port as 21, End Port as 21, Local Ip address as 192.168.0.4

similarly for other ports also. If you are asking to forward same port to different servers, I think its logically wrong.